# Android Deep linking omit certain url

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I have implemented deep linking to my app successfully but I am stuck with a problem.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
       android:host="*.example.com"
       android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This intent filter handles all the links but I don't want to catch a certain url i.e.

```
https://www.example.com/hello/redirect/
```

**What I tried so far:**

I tried entering all the URLs that I want to catch manually

```
<data
   android:host="*example.com"
   android:scheme="https"
   android:pathPrefix="/m/">
<data
   android:host="*example.com"
   android:scheme="https"
   android:pathPrefix="/c/">
<data
   android:host="*example.com"
   android:scheme="https"
   android:pathPrefix="/p/">
...
```

But then my home page URL `https://www.example.com` doesn't work.

If i use

```
android:pathPrefix="/"
```

then this will start catching all the URLs again including the url i want to omit.

I also tried using `android:pathPattern`, but it can't understand a complicated regex like this `^((?!redirect).)*$` which works fine when I try it in strings and all.

Anybody know how can I omit certain URLs?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @PLNech [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428066/6602985), I added all the URLs that I need to catch using `android:pathPrefix` and use `android:path: "/"` to catch the URL of my home page i.e. https://www.example.com/

```
 <data
   android:host="*.example.com"
   android:scheme="https"
   android:path="/"/>
 <data
  android:host="*example.com"
  android:scheme="https"
  android:pathPrefix="/m/">
 <data
  android:host="*example.com"
  android:scheme="https"
  android:pathPrefix="/c/">
 <data
  android:host="*example.com"
  android:scheme="https"
  android:pathPrefix="/p/">
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Android deep linking mechanism](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) does not provide a way to explicitly exclude some URLs: you can [either](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path) include explicitly paths with `android:path`, include paths matching a prefix with `android:pathPrefix` or matching a wildcard with `android:pathPattern` where you can use `*` or `.*`.

In your case, you will have to either use `"/"` and have **every** link to your website opened with your app (including your homepage), or have every deep link share a common prefix.

You can also have a look at airbnb's [DeepLinkDispatch](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch/) library, which seems to [allow excluding specific URLs](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch/issues/69).

Comment: What about my homepage if I don't put "/" at the end

Comment: Seems like airbnb's DeepLinkDispatch library will list (while tapping the deep link) our target app for excluded URL.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to exclude a particular URL from a certain list of URLs. What you tried was a good way to do that.

`android:pathPattern` doesn't understand the complicated regex pattern as you said.

I think the only way to solve your problem is to change the URL which you want to omit. Change the host or a part of that URL, or change the name `example.com` to, say, `example2.com/hello/redirect/`.

Comment: I get your point. That's the last resort for me. But before that,  I just need to know that can there be any solution which I can implement to solve the issue.