# How to prevent Chrome from opening App Links

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking, applinks

I have an android application say Sample App. I want to add App Links according to [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html). I was successful in implementing them, but there was an problem with Chrome. When I access the corresponding Sample Web App and there is `<a>` tag with `href="https://www.sample.com/profile"` and it's also supported by App, it opens in app instead of continuing in Chrome.
I checked documentation and it is supposed to be default behavior of Chrome. But then I came across Linkedin app. The My Network tab they have when clicked in browser continues in browser but same link if I save to docs or any other application and click it then it opens in native app.
I want to know how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because, as you said, the standard deep linking behavior is to route to the app if it is installed. This behavior is handed-off immediately when the link is clicked because your app overriders that url to be handled by app instead of Chrome.

First, I believe that you should route users to your application because its a better, more engaging experience, presumably.

If you are convinced, then I would change your manifest to strictly handle links that you want to handle. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422305/android-deep-linking-omit-certain-url) to see how to handle only certain links.

Comment: I understand the behavior and best practices, but app has subset of my web app. The question is how it can be done? We have Linkedin to verify hat it can be done